# Why can't I find the certificate in HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, ssl, curl, websphere

I pass the request through the curl along with the certificates with the following command

curl --cacert root_2.pem --cert 99usr.pem --key 99usr.key https://localhost:8443/WebServiceProject/CalculatorService -d @test-soap.xml -H "Accept: * / *" - H "Cache management: without cache" - H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflation" - H " Content type: text/xml; encoding=UTF-8"\

```
curl output
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: root_2.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=RU; O=Company; OU=00CA; CN=localhost
*  start date: Nov 18 14:05:43 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Feb 20 14:15:43 2023 GMT
*  common name: localhost (matched)
*  issuer: DC=ru; DC=rf; DC=ca; CN=Test Issuing CA 2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /WebServiceProject/CalculatorService HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8443
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Language: en-US
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0000O-g63NyHjOW2Oj3CcOjjcXi:-1; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Wed, 14 Jul 2021 09:20:05 GMT
< Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache="set-cookie, set-cookie2"
```

Then I try to read the request, but I don't find the certificate in it.

```
X509Certificate[] x509Certificates = (X509Certificate[]) httpServletRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
            if (x509Certificates == null || x509Certificates.length == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Certificate not found");
            }
```

Comment: Does the cast throw an exception or is `throw new Exception("Certificate not found");` executed?

Comment: yes it was fulfilled throw new Exception("Certificate not found");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your curl output shows no "Certificate Request" handshake message, so presumably the port you're hitting is not configured w/ TLS mutual auth in the "Quality of Protection" SSL settings in WebSphere.

Comment: If the handshake had not occurred then the request would have been rejected WebSphere?

Comment: The handshake occurs/completes, but the "Certificate Request" is an optional part of the handshake the server can send to request a certificate from the client.  From the debug output, it doesn't look like the server asked for a client certificate.  Generally, servers don't ask for them by default.